# Blocked Thread Exception While Using BR-POP and Socket

Tags: sockets, websocket, redis, vert.x, jedis

We have running 1 vert.x Server connected with redis and DB for running Messenger App. 
5~7 people(client) connected to redis simultaneously.

when we send a message to others or do some task processing via Web Socket.

```
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-4,5,main] has been blocked for 74241 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:195)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:141)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:233)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:226)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.brpop(Jedis.java:1716)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.brpop(Jedis.java:3400)
    at com.ontheit.redis.clients.AbstractRedisClient.BRPOP(AbstractRedisClient.java:59)
    at com.ontheit.redis.clients.AbstractRedisClient.BRPOP(AbstractRedisClient.java:50)
    at com.ontheit.redis.clients.RedisRequestDaemonClient.getNotify(RedisRequestDaemonClient.java:147)
    at com.ontheit.vertx.cache.CacheWorkVerticle.lambda$0(CacheWorkVerticle.java:27)
    at com.ontheit.vertx.cache.CacheWorkVerticle$$Lambda$80/1754003563.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:273)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$85/1241209246.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue$$Lambda$9/1676010932.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

we got this warning

we cant understand that warning came out with current circumstance.

[image]

we also can't understand why clients number is too high compare to real user who is using redis server.

how can we solved this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using the Vert.x Redis client. It looks like you're not. Most probably, your Redis client is a blocking one, and you can't block the Vert.x event loop threads.

Comment: yeah i know that should block the event loop and work vertices accessed to Redis.